# Can I write a paragraph and ask for corrections?

Tags: support

First, I am not sure if this place is suitable for my question

Can I write a paragraph "about any thing" and ask to to correct this paragraph?

Or if I do so I will violate the policy of English learners site..?

Comment: You have asked your question in exactly the right place. ELL Meta is for asking questions about ELL, and ELL is for asking about the correctness of your English.

Comment: You might be interested in this question & answer. [Alternative websites for proofreading](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/263/2818)

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that is specifically off-topic, under the rubric of proofreading. See the [help center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site:
>
> - Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), **unless the source of concern is clearly specified**

Note, however, that if you ask about a specific issue - the use of a specific word or phrase, for instance, or the propriety of a verb form or construction in a specific instance - we will be happy to address that.

Comment: Note that if you do ask a specific question, it is still very helpful to include your entire paragraph, so that others can understand the context.

Answer (score 2):

Proofreading is considered off-topic is because, without that limitation, ELL could easily become a proofreading service. I expect scores of bloggers, collage applicants, and resumé writers would come to ELL, essentially asking:

> *Can I improve this before I submit it?*
>
> *What changes or improvements would you suggest?*

It would simply be unfair to ask the ELL community to shoulder that burden.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to existing answers, with which I agree:

ELL wouldn’t be the useful knowledge repository that it is if the community permitted it to be cluttered with proofreading questions.

Lots of interesting aspects of learning English can come out of proofreading, but unfocused questions of any variety degrade the quality of ELL as a resource for other learners.

If you’re not sure where to start (you suspect something’s wrong, but you don’t know what it is), you might try asking here on Meta or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners). In either case, you could paste the whole block of text and ask the meta-level question of “What would be a good question about an error I’m making?”

In any case, the end result should be a focused, generalizable question that gives respondents the best chance to provide the most benefit to your understanding of the language. To that end:

- Limit questions to a single aspect of English
- Write about your understanding of that area, including description of any related confusion
- Ask a question about *why* something is the way it is, rather than whether it’s one way or another

Beyond making the site useful to future visitors and lightening the load a question places on the time and energy the community has for answering questions, forming questions this way should provide the maximum long-term benefit to *you* as a learner of English. The answers you get to a good question will provide exactly the details you need and help you build an intuition for your next encounter with that issue.